# Nesting an IIF function inside a MAX function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm tasked with analyzing a T-SQL function that repeatedly nests an IIF function inside a MAX function. Am I missing something or does this simply not change the output at all?

```
DECLARE @firstVal INT = 1;
SELECT [NotWrappedIff] = IIF(1=2, @firstVal, NULL)
SELECT [MaxWrappedIff] = MAX(IIF(1=2, @firstVal, NULL))
```

The actual code has a additional isnull, and dateadd functions nested, but the structure is the same. The false value of the nested IIFs are all NULL. Actual code:

```
SomeIdToKeep = max(iif(isnull(SomeStartTime, SomeOtherStartTime) < @parmStartTime and dateadd(hour, HourIntVal, isnull(SomeStartTime, SomeOtherStartTime)) >= @parmStartTime, SomeId, null))
```

Comment: Presumably your actual query has a `GROUP BY` somewhere so the `MAX` isn't superfluous.

Comment: Your sample code and actual code seem very different. And very hard to comment without sample data.

Comment: Thank you, @JeroenMostert no GROUP BY's exist in the function... weird.

Comment: @DaleK I tried to pull out the outer structure of the complex nesting to isolate the question about MAX (ignoring the isnull, and dateadd calculations). I provided the actual code for context.

Comment: I think for the purposes of understanding the code you have oversimplified it however. Its seems that the original code is finding the max of some values while ignoring others, given some condition. But without seeing the data to compare to the condition its difficult to guess the logic. In answer to your question though, I am fairly certain the `IIF` is causing certain values to be ignored as part of the `MAX` calculation.

Comment: Thanks, @DaleK. unfortunately - providing sample data would be a bit difficult. Are you sure about that? Look at the parenthesis structure - the IIF is nested immediately inside the MAX. So the MAX receives either a NULL, or what the other clause (of nested functions) resolve to. That's my understanding anyway - perhaps I am oversimplifying it.

Comment: Well the most obvious difference is that, even without a `GROUP BY`, `MAX` always yields exactly one value, while `IIF` may yield none or multiple. Add `FROM sys.tables` to the end of your queries to see that difference in action. Whether is needed in context is another question, it might be a copy-pasted approach.

Comment: Yeah, so as you say `max` receives either null or a value depending on the condition, well when the condition returns null to `max`, that is essentially ignoring what the actual value is, because `max` ignores nulls. So its filtering out which values to take the max from, and it looks like a date range from what you've shown. So maybe its saying whats the max value up until today, ignoring future orders (or something).

Comment: Confused, are you asking about the `1=0`, or about using `max` with no `from` or about nesting `iif` inside a `max`?

Comment: @DaleK I believe `MAX`'s ignoring of `NULL`s applies when more than one value is being evaluated, but what happens when `NULL` is the ONLY value being evaluated - seems like `NULL` gets returned by `MAX`. So this is a situation where `IFF` returns `NULL` and not other values are present.

Comment: @Charlieface sorry for the confusion - the question is about the usage of `MAX` and `IFF`. `1=0` was just there to force the second term to be returned by `IFF`.

Comment: @Alphonso77 thats why we must see more context, max will not work unless there is aggregation happening, either implicitly grouping all rows, or explicitly grouping some rows. So there will be multiple rows.

Comment: @DaleK if you run that sample code I provided, you can see `MAX` taking the output of `IFF` and returning a value (without aggregation if I in fact understand the concept).

Comment: So there is no reason why you cannot nest `iif` inside `max`, it is a scalar function, not an aggregation. (Incidentally it actually gets compiled down to `case when`). If you have `from` but no `group by` then it is run on the whole set, similar to `group by ()` except that it always returns at least one row. If there isn't even a `from` then it is the same as not using `max` at all, as there is no aggregation.

Comment: @Alphonso77 the sample you have provided is too simple, I keep saying that. Your actual code selects from a table, and that requires aggregation else you get an error. To demonstrate you need to set up a small temp table with a few rows, then it will make sense to you. And actually your sample **IS** doing implicit aggregation, its aggregating everything, which in this case is a single row because its static, but in your real example will be quite different.

Comment: All right - so I think maybe the `LEFT JOIN` (contained in the context you all are requesting - my apologies - this is proprietary code) may have the aggregation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your have over simplified the example which is why its not making sense.

The code itself performs a conditional aggregation, i.e. it returns the `MAX` value out of the rows which meet the provided condition determined by `IIF`.

This can be demonstrated as follows:

```
declare @Test table (id int, StartDate date, [Value] int);

insert into @Test (id, StartDate, [Value])
values
(1, '01-Feb-2021', 10),
(2, '02-Feb-2021', 20),
(3, '03-Feb-2021', 30);

select
    max([Value]) TrueMax
    , max(iif(StartDate < '03-Feb-2021', [Value], null)) ConditionalMax
from @Test;
```

Which returns:

| TrueMax | ConditionalMax |
| --- | --- |
| 30 | 20 |

Note: You can be sure that you are aggregating, because otherwise attempting to use `MAX` throws an error.